# Why does this script for deleting orders not work for me?

Tags: orders, delete

```
Magento 1.9.3
```

I am trying to delete all orders from our database by following the script on these pages here:

https://meetanshi.com/blog/delete-orders-in-magento/

or

https://www.simicart.com/blog/delete-orders-magento/

I have added the prefix of mgo0_ in front of all but I get the following Error:

```
TRUNCATE `mgo0_sales_order`
MySQL says: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'databaseNAME_mage277.mgo0_sales_order' does not exist.
```

**How do I need to change the script to make this work?**

Answer (score 0):

In magento 1 the table is named `sales_flat_order`